# Change placeholder text color when combobox disabled in WinRT XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In my Windows 8.1 project, I have a combo box with a custom style so that I can change the foreground color of the placeholder text.

When the combo box is disabled, this custom foreground color is too light, so I would like to be able to change this placeholder text color.

Changing the ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush only affects the actual combo box text, not the placeholder text, and I don't see any way to control the PlaceholderTextBlock foreground for different visual states.

Can the placeholder text color be controlled by visual state?

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Grid>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxArrowDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          ...
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="#FFAAAAAA" FontWeight="Normal" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
          </ContentPresenter>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brush you're looking for is named as `ComboBoxPlaceholderTextForegroundThemeBrush` under `ComboBox`'s style.

```
 .....
 <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
               HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
               Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
               Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceholderTextForegroundThemeBrush}"
               FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceholderTextThemeFontWeight}"
               Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" />
 </ContentPresenter>
 ....
```

You can separately handle placeholder foreground like this

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                               Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                            Value="Black" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: I would like to keep the custom foreground color specified in the original post, but want to be able to control the disabled foreground color.